# How would I make what the user typed for else into a variable/input?

Tags: python, if-statement, input

```
else=(x = raw_input("Enter\n")):
    print(x)
```

I have tried doing this basing it off of the correct statement...

```
x = raw_input("Enter\n")
print(x)
```

Comment: I've turned your code into code formatting. Is that what it should look like? If so, it doesn't make much sense. Can you clarify wha you are trying to do with that else bit?

Comment: You need to read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial) ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

if your doing an if statement and you wanted the input after else is ran you would just run it as normal in the if/else flow.


But depending on what you are actually trying to do its likely to have a better way to do it. Not sure your skill level but i would HIGHLY recommend Jessica McKellers basic tutorials on youtube or the basic Python tutorial like Tigerhawk recommended.

```
if something:
    print("Hello")
else:
    x = raw_input("Enter Something ")
    print(x)
```